# Negative log likelihood when using logits

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, log-likelihood

I am trying to use negative log-likelihood as a metric in my neural network. However, I have found two different implementations of the loss and I cant seem to find out which one is correct.

```
negative_log_likelihood = tf.reduce_mean(
          -tf.reduce_logsumexp(-tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
          targets, logits, from_logits=True), axis=1)
```

or

```
negative_log_likelihood = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.reduce_sum(sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
                    targets, logits, from_logits=True), axis=1))
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this post [cross entropy/log-likelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198038/cross-entropy-or-log-likelihood-in-output-layer), cross-entropy and log likelihood are different and you can not compute the log likelihood from the cross-entropy. But you can easily compute the log-likelihood directly from it's formula